# how can write bash script to get backup

Tags: linux, bash, automation, devops, backup

I want to write a bash script to backup my directories every day

this is my script

```
$ sudo tar -cvpzf /home/backup.tar.gz /home/data
```

how can I automate this

Comment: call your backup script from your crontab; and it would be better to timestamp your backups and keep a few of them

Answer (score 1):

As @Fravadona suggested, your best bet would be to use a cron job. For such a short and self-explanatory command, I wouldn't even use a script per se.

You can add a new job just typing in your terminal `sudo crontab -e` for edit (since you want to run a command with sudo, this opens `root`'s crontab). To better understand how the frequency is configured, you can use for example [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru).

Then, you can add the new entry using your preferred text editor. As suggested in the comments, you could add a timestamp to the tar file name to keep track of it.

For example, a backup that runs every day at 08:00:

```bash
0 8 * * * /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/tar -cvpzf /home/backup_`date +%s`.tar.gz /home/data
```

*Note*: The `date +%s` command returns a unix timestamp.

Comment: Replace `+%s` by for example `+%F-%H%M%S` to get a more readable time stamp.